# Git - Undoing changes

Tags: git

I'm currently trying to learn using Git within my workflow and I'd like to ask somethings  how I could do them more easily.

I usually create different braches in order to do some thing and see if they work for me. When I'm switching branches how can I keep my working directory with the files and folders that has in the last commit? So for example when I switch from branch_A to master my working dir will have the folders and files of my last commit in master branch, or when I switch to branch_B my working dir will have all from last commit in branch_B, etc etc

Comment: @AndrewC - The duplicate you linked to is itself a duplicate, plus newer than the duplicate I linked to, which is protected rather than closed a duplicate.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - The duplicate you linked to was specific to untracked files (`git clean`), the other one included both needed steps (`git reset` and `git clean`).  Whomever closed them as duplicates originally might not have understood the distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> to set my working directory just how it was until my last commit, so basicly all new -untracked files and folders and all changes to existing files will no longer exist.

To reset your changes which were not commited, just hit

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

to revert to your last commit.

I'm not sure if I got your second part of the question right, but I will try to explain it:

If you want to keep your changes and want to apply them on another branch, combine it with [Git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

```
git stash save
git reset --hard HEAD
// do what you want to do and switch branches
git stash pop
```

Comment: :Thank you for you reply. what I mean on 2nd part is to keep any changes or new files I did in the 'testing' branch I was and when I switch to another 'testing' branch those changes and untracked files don't exist, so I can create new stuff there. So basicly each time my working dir will be same as my last commit.

Comment: You can do the reset on your current branch and then `git checkout -b new_testing_branch` to branch from your current commit.

Comment: `git clean -f -d # remove untracked files`

Comment: git checkout .  would also work. :)